# Do we know the timing of all of the events in the anime?

Tags: joker-game

To the best of my knowledge, in the *Joker Game* anime, we are not consistently given information about when the different events shown occur. I do know the following:

- "Joker Game" clearly occurs shortly after the founding of D-Agency in autumn of 1937.
- "XX (Double Cross)" occurs in spring of 1939.
- "Robinson" and "Asia Express" take place in 1939.
- "Double Joker" includes a flashback that takes place six months before the main events. In the flashback, the D-Agency has recently been created; the main events then probably are in 1938.
- The spy in "Miscalculation" had a one-year stay in France planned, starting from June 15, 1939. France was occupied in June 1940, so it seems likely that "Miscalculation" is set in 1940.
- "Pursuit" makes reference to the events of "Robinson", and so must have occurred afterwards.

We also see a character in "Coffin" comment that a behind-the-scenes three-way alliance between Japan, Germany, and Italy has been formed. This restricts the possible dates of the main events of that episode, but I still do not have anything narrow enough for want of sufficient historical knowledge.

I am left without knowing when "City of Temptation", "Pursuit", "Codename: Cerberus", and "Coffin" take place. (It is obvious, for instance, that "City of Temptation" takes place when Shanghai was occupied by the Japanese, but the resulting timeframe is still rather large.) Is there any official information on when the various events happen? If not, can we make any inferences (based on details we see, or details in other adaptations of the same material) to make educated guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/4p5nh4/spoilers_joker_game_episode_12_discussion/

> the chronological order of the episodes goes as follows:
>
> D Agency founded in autumn 1937
>
> Episodes 1 & 2 ("Joker Game Part 1 & 2") - Spring 1939
>
> Episode 12 ("XX - Double Cross") - Spring 1939
>
> Episode 6 ("Asia Express") - July 25, 1939 (this is the only episode with a specific date)
>
> Episode 5 ("Robinson") - Autumn 1939
>
> Episode 7 ("Code Name: Cerberus") - Early summer 1940
>
> Episode 10 ("Pursuit") - Summer 1940
>
> Episode 3 ("Miscalculation") - Summer 1940
>
> Episodes 8 & 9 ("Double Joker Part 1 & 2") - Early autumn 1940
>
> Episode 11 ("Coffin") - Autumn 1940
>
> Episode 4 ("City of Temptation") - Summer 1941

Image from the official website of the anime : http://jokergame.jp/story/

[image: Image from the official website of the anime : http://jokergame.jp/story/]

Comment: Interesting. I realised later that "Joker Game" might be in spring (given the cherry blossoms), but placed it at most in 1938. (I assume, perhaps incorrectly, that recruitment was nearly finished when the agency was officially created.) I also knew that "Double Joker" was in autumn, but since my placement of it depended on my sense of when people would have learned of D-Agency, the year might have been wrong. Do you have any idea where these dates come from though? For instance, I couldn't find information on the date in the episode "Cerberus", unless I've missed a detail.

Comment: @Maroon : If there is not any mention of the date or season, then I think the reddit user has probably guessed it from the weather and/or some events that are related or connected to the events in other episodes. Try find it yourself. I am too lazy to rewatch it. Sorry. Good luck. :)

Comment: in some of these cases, I can understand where they got the season or year, based on some guesswork or minor historical knowledge or details within the show. In other cases, however, I can only say that the suggested date isn't implausible. In the case of Joker Game, and thus, Double Joker, I'm not convinced . . . Maybe I'll do some research of my own later, if I have time.

Comment: @Maroon : http://jokergame.jp/story/

Comment: @Maroon : Above link is from the official website of the anime. It shows the timeline of the events. However it is in Japanese. This is as much I could help. :)

Comment: @Maroon : I added the image here. :)

Comment: Thank you, I think that should confirm things, although I'd need to take a closer look. (I don't really know Japanese, but I know how to read katakana, which helps here.)

Comment: Okay, upon a closer read and some slight guesswork, I can tell that this probably confirms the Reddit user's timeline.